# HTML: What makes the CSS work in this page?

Tags: html, css

I'm really curious about this because the book I'm reading on HTML didn't clarify that. In HTML, we do not need `<!DOCTYPE html>` in order to get the browser to output pure HTML properly, i tried removing some of the things from the page yet I need to use all of the mechanics listed below in order in order to get the browser to change the font, word size, etc.

I wanted to see if I could do this but type less, as it is the CSS (font, word size, etc.) shows itself beautifully:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset "utf-8">
   <title>Corona College</title>
<style>
p {
width: 700px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
}

</head>
</style>
<body>
<p> After Southern California's soaring coronavirus caseload forced Chapman University this month to abruptly abandon plans to reopen its campus and shift to an autumn of all-remote instruction, 
the school promised that students would still get a "robust Chapman experience."</p><p>"We are paying a lot of money for tuition, and our students are not getting what we paid for,"wrote Shannon Carducci, 
whose youngest child, Ally, is a sophomore at 
Chapman, in Orange County, where the cost of attendance averages $65,000 a year.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are closing <style> after </head>. Example
</head></style> should be </style></head>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of creating a webpage with only a white background and text, this works just fine. <strike>I have not been able to answer my question</strike>...This code produces text in a browser with the correct size and font:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<html>

<meta charset "utf-8">
<title>Test title</title>

<style>
p {
width: 700px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
}
</style>


<body>
<p>test page</p>
</body>

</html>
```

the reason this wasn't working before was because the `<p>` tag was arranged so:

```
<p>
text
</p>
```

it isn't necessary to use `<head>` for this purpose even though programs other than a browser may have trouble interpreting this text, and not using that tag keeps you from including other aspects in the `<head>` tag. I prefer to only use code that is completely necessary for two reasons:

1. The less code, the easier it is to read.
2. Programming projects are MUCH easier to bug test if there is less code, if you break your code into more sections, this also makes bug testing easier.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the code:

```
<head>
<style>
p {
width: 700px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
}
</style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, To What makes the CSS work on this page?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset "utf-8">
   <title>Corona College</title>
<style>
p {
width: 700px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p> After Southern California's soaring coronavirus caseload forced Chapman University this month to abruptly abandon plans to reopen its campus and shift to an autumn of all-remote instruction, 
the school promised that students would still get a "robust Chapman experience."</p><p>"We are paying a lot of money for tuition, and our students are not getting what we paid for,"wrote Shannon Carducci, 
whose youngest child, Ally, is a sophomore at 
Chapman, in Orange County, where the cost of attendance averages $65,000 a year.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this code will be useful to you.

Thank you.

Comment: how did you do that "run code snippet" thing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to close **style** tag before **head** tag. And if you want paragraph should be responsive then you can use css **max-width** property.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Corona College</title>
<style>
p {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
After Southern California's soaring coronavirus caseload forced Chapman University this month to abruptly abandon plans to reopen its campus and shift to an autumn of all-remote instruction, 
the school promised that students would still get a "robust Chapman experience."
</p>
<p>
"We are paying a lot of money for tuition, and our students are not getting what we paid for,"wrote Shannon Carducci, whose youngest child, Ally, is a sophomore at Chapman, in Orange County, where the cost of attendance averages $65,000 a year.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i did that and it has no bearing on the output of the text, im using mozilla firefox. I'm trying to figure out what makes the output work, ill answer my own question in a little bit.

Comment: I think you are missing **<meta>** tag for viewport so you need to add **<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">** inside **<head>** tag.

Comment: is viewport JUST a word or does it have relevance inside a browser?

Comment: and no, whenever i remove the ```<p></p>```, with or without meta, the CSS fails to change the font and size of the body. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use appropriate coding style

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset "utf-8">
   <title>Corona College</title>
<style>
p {
width: 700px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p> After Southern California's soaring coronavirus caseload forced Chapman University this month to abruptly abandon plans to reopen its campus and shift to an autumn of all-remote instruction, 
the school promised that students would still get a "robust Chapman experience."</p><p>"We are paying a lot of money for tuition, and our students are not getting what we paid for,"wrote Shannon Carducci, 
whose youngest child, Ally, is a sophomore at 
Chapman, in Orange County, where the cost of attendance averages $65,000 a year.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

or you can make an external CSS file that can be linked with HTML pages.
Suppose you make "styles.css" file where you do your CSS then to link this You can use link tag inside HTML head tags as below:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
```